# Why is BlocListener not listening to my state?

Tags: flutter, state, flutter-bloc

It is little strange , that the blocListener is not listening to my state changes, and my state is null foreover, Why is that so ?

A little help or an insight would be greatly appreciated.

`user_cubit.dart`

```
  UserCubit() : super(UserInitialState()) {
    emit(UserMainLoadingState());
    _firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(_currentUser?.uid) // or whatever your collection name is
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      event.exists
          ? {
              print("User Exists"),
              emit(state.copyModel(
                  userModel: UserModel.fromjson(event.data()!, event.id))), // Here I am using copyModel , as a additional method
              emit(UserExists(
                  userModel: UserModel.fromjson(event.data()!, event.id)))
            }
          : {print("There is no such user"), emit(UserNotExists())};
    });
  }
```

`user_state.dart`

```
class UserState extends Equatable {
  final UserModel? userModel;
  const UserState({this.userModel});

  UserState copyModel({required UserModel userModel}) {
    return UserState(userModel: userModel);
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [userModel];
}


class UserExists extends UserState {
  UserExists({required UserModel userModel}) : super(userModel: userModel) {

  }
}
```

`my_widget.dart`

```
 body: BlocListener<UserCubit, UserState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
              print("I am inside the listener");
            if (state.userModel != null) {
              print("State is ${state.runtimeType}");

            }
          },
          child: <My widget>
```

`console`

```
I/flutter ( 5029): I am inside the UserExists state and the user is :avatar boy
I/flutter ( 5029):  fullName krrrt
I/flutter ( 5029):  dob 19/1/2022
I/flutter ( 5029):  email rd@xddf.co
I/flutter ( 5029):  phone 12222222255
```

Suprisingly the print `I am inside the listener` is never executed.

And state is always null and prints from inside the listener is never executed , in `listener` i want to initialize some variables like textfield, but my state is always null, I am not able to figure out why, though i have updated the state and state has value inside it.

A little help would be highly appreciated

Edit:

`User_model.dart`

```
class UserModel {
  final String avatar;
  final String fullName;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final String dob;
  final String email;
  String? id;

  UserModel(
      {required this.avatar,
      required this.dob,
      required this.email,
      required this.fullName,
      required this.phoneNumber});

  factory UserModel.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json, String id) {
    return UserModel(
        avatar: json['avatar'],
        dob: json["dob"],
        email: json['email'],
        fullName: json['fullName'],
        phoneNumber: json['phoneNumber']);
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'fullName': fullName,
      'dob': dob,
      'avatar': avatar,
      'email': email,
      'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    // TODO: implement toString
    return "avatar $avatar \n fullName $fullName \n dob $dob \n email $email\n phone $phoneNumber ";
  }
}
```

Comment: does `userModel` extends also equatable, or does it have `==` operator ovveriden ?

Comment: @Gwhyyy Thank you , I didn't actually get you, UserModel is a simple Model which has fromJson and toJson method, I have updated the code to clarify

Comment: wait, I will explain

Comment: maybe you can try calling `listenWhen`

Comment: @MasterTechie did you find any solution? I'm exactly facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `props` of your `UserState` that is required to be overridden when you do `extends Equatable` is used to compare trigger difference by the equality of
previous and current states `UserState` in order to emit it.

Well for primitives like `int`, and `String`..., they already you don't need to be concerned about them since they already have their own `==` shipped from the Dart SDK :

```
1 == 2 // false
1 == 1 // true
```

This is not right for custom-made classes that you create, when creating a `UserModel` class, it doesn't have an `==` relation, so when the `emit()`  of the `UserCubit` will try to compare previous and current `UserState`, what tells it the difference is the comparison of props, right? so in your case it will compare `props` elements which are only `UserModel` :

```
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [userModel];
```

now here is the trick, you can try by yourself manually comparing two `userModel` :

```
final first = userModel(/* properties */);
final second = userModel(/* same properties as first's */);

first == second // false
```

even if they have as an example the same properties, they will always fail to compare them and returns `false`, buy this every time two `UserState` be compared it will be the same, and the `emit()` will be just ignored, which will not trigger the `BlocListener`.

The solution is that you will need to define the equality relation of the `userModel`, you need to use `Equatable` also for this :

```
class UserModel extends Equatable { // add this
//...

@override
List<Object?> get props => [avatar, fullName, phoneNumber, dob, email];
}
```

Comment: Thank you , for your explanation, but unfortunately,still nothing changed, and listener print is still not getting printed