# state is always null in flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-cubit

I am facing this weird issue, where though I have set the state, but the value when accessed  in init state is showing null !!

`user_cubit.dart`

```
  UserCubit() : super(UserInitialState()) {
    emit(UserMainLoadingState());
    _firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(_currentUser?.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      event.exists
          ? {
              emit(UserExists(
                  userModel: UserModel.fromjson(event.data()!, event.id)))
            }
          : {print("There is no such user"), emit(UserNotExists())};
    });
  }
```

`user_state.dart`

```
class UserState extends Equatable {
  final UserModel? userModel;
  const UserState({this.userModel});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [userModel];
}

class UserExists extends UserState {
  UserExists({required UserModel userModel}) : super(userModel: userModel) { // Here the state is received
    print("I am inside the UserExists state and the user is :$userModel");
  }
}
```

`myWidget.dart`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
     _userState = const UserState();
    print("I am inside the initState The value of userstate is ${_userState.userModel}");  // This prints null , though i have set the state and console logs the state and it is confirmed that state exists why isn't this not null
    if (_userState.userModel != null) {
     print("user is ${_userState.userModel.toString()}"); 
     }
    super.initState();
  }
```

Console log:

```
I/flutter ( 5029): I am inside the UserExists state and the user is :avatar boy
I/flutter ( 5029):  fullName krrrt
I/flutter ( 5029):  dob 19/1/2022
I/flutter ( 5029):  email rd@xddf.co
I/flutter ( 5029):  phone 12222222255

I/flutter ( 5029): I am inside the initState The value of userstate is null
```

Though the `userState's` `userModel` has value, why can't i access that in the `initState.

My tries :

I have used BlocListener, still the state remains null, I'm hell confused.

```
body: BlocListener<UserCubit, UserState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
              print("I am inside the listener");    // this line is never printed
            if (state.userModel != null) {
              print("State is ${state.runtimeType}"); // But if the state has some value, why isn't this being printed !!!??

            }
          },
          child: <My widget>
```

Comment: If you are talking about initial state on blocListner, it doesnt call 1st change

Comment: @YeasinSheikh thank you , the posted answer help me to get through , but i am confused why my listener is not working could you please look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75193391/why-is-bloclistener-not-listening-to-my-state